# Is there any library to connect to Dota2 game server?

Tags: reverse-engineering, steam

I am looking for a way to create a program to get real-time game data from live Dota2 games. In the official Dota2 client there are several ways of doing it. You can connect to a game server through DotaTV, you can join your friend's game or you can join a lobby as a spectator or a broadcaster before the game starts.

I think, all these ways use the same protocol to connect to a game server and to retrieve game data. So could you, please, propose any library for doing this? If there is no such a library, could you please give me some advice about how to create it by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no library, but there is a console command `_record file_name` which tells Dota2 client to write replay of the currently played or spectated game to file. Than you can parse this file using Dota2 replay parser ([Skadistat Clarity](https://github.com/skadistats/clarity) for example). They already have [example](https://github.com/skadistats/clarity-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/skadistats/clarity/examples/livesource/Main.java) for realtime parsing.